# German video news with transcription

Tags: learning, resource

Inspired by [an answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/3354/1138), I wonder if there are good places to watch simple-language multimedia on current topics with subtitles or transcription (and ideally English translation).

For example, [Spiegel TV](http://www.spiegel.de/video/spiegeltv/) provides a lot of informative content, but it's not easy for me to understand as videos don't seem to exactly correspond to articles.

What I have in mind is something like Deutsche Welle's [Langsam gesprochene Nachrichten](http://www.dw-world.de/dw/0,,2068,00.html) but longer, with video, and with vocabulary tailored for beginners.

Answer (score 8):

Deutsche Welle is the best possible page for German language learners, I know no other news agency that would do so much for teaching German worldwide.

[On the same page](http://www.dw-world.de/dw/0,,2146,00.html) you are referencing in your question there is also a video section called "Deutsch Lernen mit Videos" (s. picture) where you can find 161 different short video clips tailored for beginners.

[image: Deutsche Welle]

Answer (score 7):

[Yabla German](http://german.yabla.com/) has videos along with the transcription:

> Yabla German is an online video magazine for German learners who wish to improve their language skills. Authentic German videos include television programs, music videos, interviews, documentaries, and travel. Only Yabla German offers captions in multiple languages, pitch-correct slow play, integrated dictionaries and listening exercises.

[Here is some free demo videos if you want to check it out](http://german.yabla.com/demo.php), for instance:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Euronews in German](http://de.euronews.com/) provides videos and word-by-word transcripts of daily news.

The transcripts may not correspond 100% to the audio in the video (few words are changed by the speaker or the sentence order is changed) but they are very useful.

Answer (score 1):

[Nachrichten Leicht](http://www.nachrichtenleicht.de/) is another one that I haven't seen suggested yet.

Comment: That site does not seem to me to be a good source for language learners.

Comment: I disagree.  I'm a language learner and I have found it to be a good source. It is explicitly designed to use simple language. See here: http://www.nachrichtenleicht.de/was-ist-nachrichtenleicht-de/ It is at a good level for practicing reading and listening skills if you are near my level -- probably about at A2. If you compare it to "real" news sites and read the "about" page, it is clear that it is designed to be simple so it's either for language learners, children, idiots, or all of the above. Note they even have audio that reads the text slowly aloud -- what more could you want?

Answer (score 0):

This is [just one video](http://www.tagesschau.de/inland/wulffruecktritt104.html), but it seems to be just what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Bayerische Rundfunk is great.  It has subtitles and you can get it on your cell phone. 
http://www.br.de/mediathek/video/suche/tag-suche-mediathek-100.html?q=Untertitel&t=tags#teaser=275143a5-2e7b-4184-9c44-8ce8f6b17271&jump=teaser